# My object drops error when I call another object inside

Tags: python, oop, object

I programmed a Snake game with Pyqt4.

I have a serious problem dealing with my objects. The thing is that I have 4 objects( I didn't include the two left because I think doesen't have importance but i can upload if is necessary) and when Screen object calls Example object this drops an error and it doesen't work. But if Example creates a var with Screen object doesen't drop error!

```
class Screen(QtGui.QWidget):#This class wrapp the game with the snake and the food
comprovamenjar = 0 
def __init__(self):
    super(Screen,self).__init__()
    self.initUI()
    self.snake = Snake()
    self.menjar = Menjar()
    self.example = Example() #< --------------------------------This provoke error
def initUI(self):
    pass       

def paintEvent(self,e): #We paint stuff..
#The code from below didn't work also
    """if self.snake.coordenadax < 0 or self.snake.coordenadax > self.height or self.snake.coordenaday < 0 or self.snake.coordenaday > self.width :
        #self.example.timer.stop()
        pass
    else:"""
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin( self )
    self.snake.pintacap( qp,self.food)#Paint Snake's Head
    self.snake.pintacos( qp,self.food)#Paint Snake's Body
    self.comprovamenjar = self.snake.pintacos#Check food
    self.menjar.pinta( qp,self.snake)#Paint Food
    qp.end()

class Example(QtGui.QWidget): #This Wrapp again the game with all the stuff
p = None
def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()
def keyPressEvent(self, e): #Keyboard functions
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
        direccio = 3
    elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
        direccio = 2
    elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
        direccio = 1
    elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
        direccio = 0
    self.p.serp.startup = 1
    self.p.serp.direccio(direccio,self.p)      
def initUI(self): #Screen options
    #Screen
    self.p = Screen()
    self.p.setParent(self)
    self.p.move(0,0)
    self.p.resize(self.p.height(),self.p.width())
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.p.amplada = self.p.width()
    self.p.alcada = self.p.height()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.p.repaint)#colbac
    self.timer.start(15)##########################################Snake's Speed Movement
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, self.p.amplada, self.p.alcada)
    self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
    self.show()
    self.setFocus()


def main():

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The error is this:

```
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 169, 
in <module> main() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 164, 
in main ex = Example() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 132, 
in __init__ self.initUI() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 146, 
in initUI self.p = Screen() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 104, 
in __init__ self.ex = Example()#<------------------------------------------------ 
The problem File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 132, 
in __init__ self.initUI() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 146, 
in initUI self.p = Screen() 
File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 104, in __init__ self.ex = Example()#<------------------------------------------------ The problem File "C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\GarciaMarcSerp1.py", line 132, in __init__
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you fix your indentation in the question? It's hard to evaluate what's going wrong in Python code that doesn't have the indentation right.

Comment: Aixo es per flipar, et dius Marc Garcia i fas codi python, pues ja som dos! XD

Comment: in all the exception trace seems to be missing the last part, can you please provide that bit with the final error?

Comment: @Blckknght What I have to fix ? It seems right for me,only the ' symbol but doesen't make misunderstanding.

Comment: @markcial The error is repeating because of the self.timer, ||*||

Comment: The timer property is set in the `QtGui.QWidget` class? because doesnt seem to be initialized anywhere, if it is not started in the superclass seems to be missing

Comment: @BugFixer: None of your code is indented under the `class` statements, so it's not entirely clear where one class ends and the next begins. This is probably just an issue with the code copied into Stack Overflow, not with your original code, but it makes interpreting your code a bit more difficult for us, and could potentially be hiding bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an infinite recursion in the construction of your objects. Each `Screen` instance tries to create an `Example` instance to store in `self.example`, but each `Example` instance tries to create a `Screen` instance to store in `self.p`. Eventually Python hits the recursion limit and gives up, raising an exception like what you've partially quoted.

You need to break the cycle of object creation. Perhaps your `Example` class could take a `Screen` object as an argument to `__init__`? Then `Screen` could pass itself as that object.

Here's some quick code to show what I mean:

```
class Screen(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # other init stuff
        self.example = Example(self)     # pass self to the Example constructor

    # other methods


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, screen):          # take screen as a parameter
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI(screen)              # pass it along to initUI

    # other methods, etc

    def initUI(self, screen):            # take screen as a parameter
        self.p = screen                  # use the passed screen rather than creating one

        # do other stuff with self.p, same as before
```

Comment: that's what happen. But the problem is that I need in Screen object some stuff from Example and in Example some stuff from screen. And I can't do it because happen this.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I suggest in the second paragraph? I will update with some code examples of how to do what I suggested, but it's not very complicated.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code again, I may have the solution backwards. Since you're starting out with creating the Example instance, you might want it to pass `self` to the `Screen` constructor, rather than the other way around. The logic is the same though.